# specific url bypass custom authentication filter not working with spring websecurity configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a custom authentication filter, and I want all urls beginning with "/api/**" except for "/ping" to go to all the security chain filters including my custom filter. I tried to add ignore pattern in the web security configuration, but it's not working: the request with "/ping" will always end up going into the custom filter.

This is my web configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
      webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/ping");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()        
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll();    
    }        
}
```

After Spring boot starts, I can see `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` has been created for both url patterns which is not supposed to be happening.

```
2016-01-21 16:58:01.042  INFO 6650 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/ping'], []
2016-01-21 16:58:01.043  INFO 6650 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/api/**'], []
2016-01-21 16:58:01.098  INFO 6650 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@695fd199, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@39df299d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5f43f2cc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@23a4d0ad, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@31fa8663, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@35e52479, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5d39a5fc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@28a18a3d, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3dffe958, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@40c2a999, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@43f059e6]
```

Is there any specific configuration I need to do for my filter? How to make it work? Thanks

Comment: `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` implements `SecurityFilterChain`, which, according Spring docs, 'Defines a filter chain which is capable of being matched against an HttpServletRequest. in order to decide whether it applies to that request.' I think the fact that a `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` is being created for the '/ping' pattern is ok. With that said, I'm not sure why it's not working as expected. Everything you posted looks correct to me.

Have you tested to check whether accessing the '/ping' url requires authorized requests?

Comment: when I do "/ping", it leads to 500 as a result of authentication failure in custom filter, it does not show unauthorized request. And if I try anything other than "/ping" or"/api/**", it still does not show 40x, instead, everything goes into the custom filter, which means the http configure part is not working properly as well...